# Nested quantifier

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have this PowerShell (v5.1) script that is driving me crazy:

```
#Installed Software
$InstalledSW = Get-Package | select name

#Managed Software
$ManagedSW = @("7-Zip", "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC", "AIMP", "Filezilla", "GIMP", "InfraRecorder", "LibreOffice", "Microsoft OneDrive", "Firefox", 
               "Notepad++", "Notepad++ (32-bit x86)", "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)", "PDFCreator", "PuTTY", "Skype", "TeamViewer", "TightVNC", "Typora", 
               "VLC", "WinSCP")
               
#Missing software
$ManagedSW | ForEach-Object {
    if (!($InstalledSW -Match $_)) {
        Write-Host "Install: $_"
    }
}
```

I have tried to escape Notepad ++ in all the ways I know but it keeps proposing the error:

```
analisi di "Notepad++" - Quantificatore annidato +. in corso...
In C:\Users\User\Desktop\test-script.ps1:8 car:9
+     if (!($InstalledSW -Match $_)) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

analisi di "Notepad++ (32-bit x86)" - Quantificatore annidato +. in corso...
In C:\Users\User\Desktop\test-script.ps1:8 car:9
+     if (!($InstalledSW -Match $_)) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

analisi di "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)" - Quantificatore annidato +. in corso...
In C:\Users\User\Desktop\test-script.ps1:8 car:9
+     if (!($InstalledSW -Match $_)) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think you should try to play with `-in`/`-notin` operators. For example: `if ($_ -notin $InstalledSW)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-match` operator uses regex, so in order to have that work in your code, you need to escape all characters that have special meaning in Regular Expressions like `+`, `(` and `)` with backslashes.

This should work:

```
#Installed Software
$InstalledSW = Get-Package | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#Managed Software
$ManagedSW = '7-Zip', 'Adobe Acrobat Reader DC', 'AIMP', 'Filezilla', 'GIMP', 'InfraRecorder', 
             'LibreOffice', 'Microsoft OneDrive', 'Firefox', 'Notepad++', 'Notepad++ (32-bit x86)', 
             'Notepad++ (64-bit x64)', 'PDFCreator', 'PuTTY', 'Skype', 'TeamViewer', 'TightVNC', 
             'Typora', 'VLC', 'WinSCP'
           
#Missing software
$ManagedSW | ForEach-Object {
    if (!($InstalledSW -match [regex]::Escape($_))) {
        Write-Host "Install: $_"
    }
}
```

But in this case, you could also use the `-like` operator with wildcards on either side of the `$_` as in:

```
#Installed Software
$InstalledSW = Get-Package | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#Managed Software
$ManagedSW = '7-Zip', 'Adobe Acrobat Reader DC', 'AIMP', 'Filezilla', 'GIMP', 'InfraRecorder', 
             'LibreOffice', 'Microsoft OneDrive', 'Firefox', 'Notepad++', 'Notepad++ (32-bit x86)', 
             'Notepad++ (64-bit x64)', 'PDFCreator', 'PuTTY', 'Skype', 'TeamViewer', 'TightVNC', 
             'Typora', 'VLC', 'WinSCP'
           
#Missing software
$ManagedSW | ForEach-Object {
    if (!($InstalledSW -like "*$_*")) {
        Write-Host "Install: $_"
    }
}
```

<sup>and there is also `-notmatch` and `notlike`</sup>